# Understanding how VS parses CSS in .ascx docs

Tags: asp.net-mvc, css

I have a number of documents (in an MVC app) that exist solely to be called by:

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("showLoginStatus"); %>
```

While editing the file in VS (08) the CSS class selectors used within this page all toss 'class not defined' warnings since the stylesheet isn't referenced in this file but in the 'parent'.

The page renders correctly when called - how do I clue VS into the fact that a definition exists?

thx

Comment: This also happens on regular asp.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like VS does not understand site relative paths, as described in [this article](http://weblogs.asp.net/jeffwids/archive/2009/06/07/why-does-visual-studio-not-resolve-my-css-class-names.aspx).

So, to answer your question, either change the CSS URLs to be fully qualified, or live with the error...